# In graphql what is difference between a `type query` and `extend type query`?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, spring-graphql, netflix-dgs

In graphql what is difference between a `type query` and `extend type query`?

Ex: difference between

```
type Query {
    product(id: String!): Product
}
```

and

```
extend type Query {
    DeviceDetail(devId: String!): DeviceDetail
}
```

Will appreciate if you could add an example for your explanation.

Comment: You can only declare a `type` once, but you can `extend` it multiple times

Comment: @Bergi - +1. will appreciate if you can add an answer with an example or provide any doc/article reference.

Comment: @Bergi - you mean or refer to the schema file. In schema file `You can only declare a type once, but you can extend it multiple times`. Is this what you mean.

Comment: Where else if not in a schema file would you find this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object extension is supported by the GraphQL spec](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Object-Extensions) as a way to add new properties to an existing type.

In this case, you will find `extend type Query` in some schemas as a way to "modularize" a schema, for example:

in `schema.graphqls`:

```
type Query {
  greeting: String
}
```

in `book.graphqls`:

```
extend type Query {
  bookById(id: ID!): Book
}

type Book {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  author: Author
}

type Author {
  name: String
}
```

Without this, you would need to either declare all queries in the same schema file, or you would get an error when GraphQL parses the schema files as the `Query` type is defined several times.

Other apps use ["namespacing"](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/technotes/TN0012-namespacing-by-separation-of-concern/) as a way to better organize the schema and avoid flattening all queries under the same type.